# Python 3.6: must be str, not bytes error with playsound module

Tags: python

I wrote an incredibly simple code just to check if the module is working, but I keep getting 'must be str, not bytes' error.

Here's the code:

```
from playsound import playsound

playsound('C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\Müzik\\January\\The Rolling Stones - Paint It, Black (Official Lyric Video).mp3')
```

And here's the exact error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/playsound/play_sound/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
playsound('C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\Müzik\\January\\The Rolling Stones - Paint It, Black (Official Lyric Video).mp3')
File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\playsound.py", line 34, in _playsoundWin
winCommand('open "' + sound + '" alias', alias)
File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\playsound.py", line 29, in winCommand
'\n    ' + errorBuffer.value)
TypeError: must be str, not bytes
```

Appreciate the help.

Comment: According to the [pypi page for the playsound module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/playsound/1.2.1), "I’ve only tested playsound it with Python 2.7 on Windows 7 and OS X 10.11". That tells me that it might not be compatible with Python 3.6.

Comment: @RandomDavis Yeah, I agree. Python 3.X treats `bytes` and `string` differently.

Answer (score 1):

That's a bug of playsound with Python 3 on windows apparently:
[Doesn't work with python 3.5 under windows 10](https://github.com/TaylorSMarks/playsound/issues/2)